# Grammatical error in the Stack Exchange API documentation is unacceptable!

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, grammar

There are a few grammatical errors in the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

[image: FAIL]

This should [*obviously*](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe) read “Delete a comment identified by ***its*** id.” This isn't 4chan!

Comment: Comments about punctuation... with multiple exclamation marks?

Comment: lols ꕶꕶꕶꕶꕶꕶꕶꕶꕶꕶ

Comment: It's preferred to point out a grammatical error without the excess moral revolt.

Comment: @djechlin Is that a fact?

Comment: @sehe it's my opinion, much as the title of this question and the first comment are.

Comment: @sehe It is.  There are people who prefer it (like djechlin).  Therefore, it is preferred.

Comment: Somewhere the author of this documentation is grinning, thinking "that took them way too long to notice".

Comment: @Bart, or they're busy building a giant apostrophe.

Comment: OMG!!! Bad grammar is something up with which we should not put!

Comment: *"This isn't 4chan!"*: I've been doing it all wrong the whole time!!

Comment: Its saying you're requested task is compleated?

Comment: @Ben Good point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true.  It should be fixed.  The degree of intensity with which you push your point may be a bit excessive.  While we're at it, the description for `/users/{ids}/questions/featured
/me/questions/featured` has an erroneous comma.  Arguably, the description for `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}` should have a period instead of a comma (going by the format of the page as a whole).